# How to implement my own finisher in a collector?

Tags: lambda, java-8, collectors

Welcome people!

I am wondering how to implement my own finisher which is not trival, like identity function.
The header of my collector is

```
public class SequentialPPSCollector<T> implements
    Collector<Pair<T, Double>, List<Pair<T, Double>>, List<T>> {...}
```

Inside there is a finisher method which should transform `List<Pair<T, Double>>` into `List<T>`

```
@Override
public Function<List<Pair<T, Double>>, List<T>> finisher() {
    return ...
}
```

This does the job

```
return list -> list
       .stream()
       .map(Pair::getLeft)
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how you can transform a `List<Pair<T, Double>>` into `List<T>`:

```
List<T> listOfT = list.stream()
                      .map(Pair::getFirst)
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

So your finisher function could looks like this:

```
@Override
public Function<List<Pair<T, Double>>, List<T>> finisher() {
    return list -> list.stream().map(Pair::getFirst).collect(toList());
}
```

---

Although this example is a bit simple because in this case you could probably declare your collector like this:

```
class SequentialPPSCollector<T> implements Collector<Pair<T, Double>, List<T>, List<T>> {...}
```

and let the accumulator grab the type T of the pair object:

```
@Override
public BiConsumer<List<T>, Pair<T, Double>> accumulator() {
    return (list, p) -> list.add(p.getFirst());
}
```

so that your finisher is simply the identity function. The first part of the answer should give you a starting point though.

Comment: "Lowercase L" looks just like "one", therefore it should not be used as a variable name...

Comment: Oh no, now I felt morally obligated to understand what exactly a finisher method is supposed to do, in order to decide whether the answer is right :) But I found no further reason to complain, +1

Comment: Yes, but it does not work properly since is `getFirst`, I gave +1 though.

Comment: @SzymonRoziewski What does not work properly? I assumed that your `Pair` class have a `getFirst` method that returns the value of type T hold by the current pair instance you're operating with.

Comment: I mean, in Pair there were no such a method.

Comment: @SzymonRoziewski Well I couldn't guess the method's name :-)

Comment: That might work but the question seems to be an XY problem though. It would make more sense to collect into lists holding the left elements in the first place rather than applying an entire conversion finisher to the result. — Oh I see you are already hinting into that direction…

Comment: @Holger That's why I made a suggestion with another collector and its `BiConsumer` alternative (though I believe what the OP wants to do can be achieved without a custom collector, but maybe it's an exercise...).

Comment: Right, I overlooked it at the first sight, mostly because the newer edit of the question indicates that the OP is ignoring it…